# Blank page and 301 redirect

Tags: fatal-error

I woke up to the white screen of death problem and it seems to be a Wordpress problem.

I'm running several domains on a Debian 3.16.7 box running nginx 1.6.2, mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.46, Wordpress 4.4 (Clifford).

I have three sites using Wordpress siteA, siteB and siteC.  All three were working last night but this morning siteC is giving a white page of death.

curl -v "http://siteC.com/"

```
*   Trying x.203.1.130...
* Connected to siteC.com (x.203.1.130) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: siteC.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.6.2
< Date: Wed, 06 Jan 2016 16:17:37 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Link: <http://siteC.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
< 
* Connection #0 to host siteC.com left intact
```

I've placed a php file with phpinfo() in the root directory and I can access this fine.  So trying the full path to the index.php file.

curl -v "http://siteC.com/index.php"

```
*   Trying x.203.1.130...
* Connected to siteC.com (x.203.1.130) port 80 (#0)
> GET /index.php HTTP/1.1
> Host: siteC.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.6.2
< Date: Wed, 06 Jan 2016 16:15:42 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: http://siteC.com/
< 
* Connection #0 to host siteC.com left intact
```

I read somewhere to try and disable the active theme by renaming the active theme folder on the server. Did this. No change. I then renamed the wp-content/plugins folder and created a blank plugins replacement. Again, after full restart, no change.

I added debug defines to wp-config.php but there is no output.

The user defined in wp-config.php can access the mysql database.

I'm using mercurial source control and can not see any changes in any wp files that might be causing this.

Both siteA and siteB continue to operate just fine.
To verify this is just Wordpress I change the nginx configuration to use a different root directory which does not have the wordpress files in it. This works fine.

Comment: I am reviewing this answer. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/191772/white-screen-error-for-a-custom-theme?rq=1  The only thing I haven't tried is to look at memory issues. Will do that next.

Comment: .. Done.  There is not a lot but the system isn't hitting a limit.

Comment: Edit /index.php and comment out define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);  The 301 redirect status disappears and I get http 200 OK (but no wordpress content).

Comment: Maybe you could try a clean vanilla install (after backing up everything)

Comment: Clean install, of course, works. That includes creating a new database for the site. But now, if I try to restore content from the system will I not get the same problem?   BTW, the problem site is still intact and can be enabled any time.  I may re-enable with a dev.siteC.com domain and try to resolve the problem further.

Comment: ok if that works, then that's good news - then you've at least narrowed down the scope of the problem ;-) Good idea to spin up a dev install where you can add one plugin at a time, rule out core file corruption, test your theme, check for hacks? etc.

Comment: The fact that the 301 goes away when you disable themes makes me suspicious... and the fact that it apparently suddenly happened overnight.

Comment: FYI, I only added the new twenty sixteen theme but I also removed several of the older default themes.   I agree that the 301 error going away suggests a theme issue but I'll keep an open mind.  This white-page-of-death situation is challenging because of the lack of insight possible to locate the problem. I was able to add echo statements into the php loading process but, only to a point. There is clearly an un caught exception happening somewhere.